# Poke-home Design, 4 pin (8 pads)

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount

Link: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/KYOCERA-AVX/009276004021006?qs=QtI0yD1FyOOQ3ADj%252BahmrQ%3D%3D

The way I read this, the pads for 5-8 are connected to 1-4 respectively, and are not needing to be wired on my pcb, correct?

Is there a benefit to putting a net between 1 and 5 on my design?

Answer (score 5):

From the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/40/PokeHomeHorizontal_00_9276-3165415.pdf) it is highly suggestive that you to connect both pads for each terminal:

[image: Datasheet showing land pattern connections]

Furthermore, from that datasheet we have the following two statements:

> By incorporating a dual-contact design we were able to maximize current rating (6 Amps) and minimize PCB space. ...
>
> ...
> The dual-contact design also provides two solder points
> for each wire eliminating the need for external anchor tabs.

I read that as implying that the reason for providing both contacts is to increase the current handling capabilities. By only using a single contact you would most likely have to de-rate the power handling capabilities accordingly.

Having both connections is also provides additional mechanical strength to the connector.

Unless there is a very good reason not to, personally I would be sure to connect both contacts to the net.